# Understanding Ember.JS itemController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am going through EmberJS documentation and ran into a stumbling block here:

```
ITEM CONTROLLER
It is often useful to specify a controller to decorate individual items in the ArrayController while iterating over them. This can be done in the ArrayController definition:

App.SongsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'song'
});
```

Not entirely sure what the purpose of `itemController` here. Does the `song` property now get proxied to an `ArrayController` named `App.SongsController`? What exactly is `itemController` doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When each element in the Songs array is used in some fashion (i.e. rendered in an {{each}} loop), every song will have its own controller instantiated. So you could have a listing of songs and each song could have its own properties (like `isPlaying`) or you could write `action` handlers to respond to user interaction `play` or `pause`.

Your `SongController` would exist for each of the songs in the array.

```
App.SongController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isPlaying: false,
  actions: {
    someAction: ...
  }
});
```

If you don't need these properties or for the action to be handled on this controller, you could leave off the itemController.